# Connect ARCore Android with Desktop via web (javascript) or standalone (Java)

Tags: javascript, java, augmented-reality, arcore

I am working on ARCore android and I am able to display augmented models on android and also to host them on other android devices using cloud anchors.

Now I am trying to connect that android app with desktop computer, it can be either a Javascript which I can use as web app, or a standalone application which I can develop using Java (Eclipse) or C.

So far I do not find any luck working with web api, now I wanted to ask if there is any way I can develop an application in Java for desktop where I can display the augmented objects created from android devices.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to mirror the screen from your Android to your desktop, or will you have a camera on the desktop also and you want to be able to display the renderable at the right location when you move the desktop's camera around?

Comment: Yes, I just want to mirror the ARCore camera on desktop or web app.

Comment: If you search for 'Android screen streaming sdk' you should find a few examples that may help you - many are open source: https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream, https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy,

Comment: Okay, will try the "ScreenStream".Thanks.